Medieval Logical Interpretations of the Word "All"
Paraphrasing the Philosopher (Aristotle): Forms of speech are either simple or composite. If expressions are simple,  then they are neither true nor false. With this said, did some Medieval logicians treat quantified statements such as all Xs are men as simple expressions that are neither true nor false? Also, how did Medieval logicians interpret the term “All”? I ask because from a modern-day perspective, we treat the word “all” to mean everything. Yet it seems that the Medievals, treated the word “all” to mean something that varies with context.

In modern logic, we do not treat “all” to mean 'everything'. The domain of discourse, over which quantifiers range, is usually regimented to be a precisely specified set subject to axioms of set theory. If further restriction is required the restricted quantifier ∀x∈S construction is used, where S a context-dependent subset. See Novaes on medieval suppositional approaches and Klima on contrasting them to modern quantification.

Thank you for the constructive feedback. I didn’t know that and thank you for the references.
